# SQL Server's `mssql-conf setup`, error Aborted sudo

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017

When I run `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` to configure SQL Server 2017 I get the following error,

```
/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/invokesqlservr.sh: line 15: 12710 Aborted                 sudo -EH -u mssql /bin/bash -c "$CMDLINE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` disables core dump

```
 To prevent the disclosure of potentially sensitive information, sudo disables core dumps by default while it is executing (they are re-enabled for the command
 that is run).  This historical practice dates from a time when most operating systems allowed setuid processes to dump core by default.  To aid in debugging
 sudo crashes, you may wish to re-enable core dumps by setting “disable_coredump” to false in the sudo.conf(5) file as follows:

       Set disable_coredump false
```

The `Aborted` above is actually generated from this

```
sudo -EH -u mssql /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
Aborted
```

Which is actually,

```
sudo -EH -u mssql sh
$ /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Make sure you have [a new copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu#install). In the event you updated your distro, you may have to re-add the repository and key.** A core dump, may or may not be normal practice for Microsoft, from their own docs, `license_Eval_Linux.txt`

> 2. TIME-SENSITIVE SOFTWARE. The software will stop running one hundred eighty days after you install it. You will not receive any other notice. You may not be able to access data used with the software when it stops running.